# Как прикрепить ViewModel к UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, usercontrol

Как прикрепить ViewModel к UserControl? В случае с window всегда делал так:

```
        new MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new MainVm()
        };
```

Если делать так для UserControl то компилятор ругается. Как нужно действовать в данной ситуации?

**P.S.** Для общей картины обьясню  к какому эффекту я стремлюсь: есть главное окно, и в зависимости от нажатий пользователся должны отображатся разные, никак не связанные между собой данные. Поэтому для каждых из этих данных я хочу создать отдельные UserControl и Vm, и по надобности просто подменять один UserControl на другой. Если у меня неправильный подход, поправьте меня.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Контрол не должен устанавливать себе сам `DataContext`. `DataContext` должен устанавливать родительский элемент. Делайте как-то так:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding CurrentUser}"/>
        <local:MyAnotherUserControl DataContext="{Binding Tracks}"/>
        <local:MyThirdUserControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedTags}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

То есть: нужные VM для частей, которые представляются в виде контролов, должны быть в `MainVM` как свойства. (Таким образом, кстати, все VM смогут общаться через центральную VM.)

Надеюсь, вы поняли идею.

---

Кстати, и главное окно тоже не должно создавать себе VM. Обычно делается так:

```
<Application x:Class="Namespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!-- убрал StartupUri -->
</Application>
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    MainVM mainVM = new MainVM();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Идею уловил. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!