# ViewModel Locator

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

У меня есть 3 `ViewModel`: базовая, и 2 дочерних. Хочу при помощи `ViewModelLocator` иметь возможность управлять свойством, которое находится в базовой ВМ, из дочерних, так чтобы они работали с одним и тем же экземпляром, а не каждый со своим, и соответственно обе реагировали на изменения. Конкретно в базовой ВМ есть bool свойство, которое должно меняться из других ВМ.
Пользовался этой статьей(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821028.aspx). Создал в `App.xaml` экземпляр `ViewModelLocator`, сам класс должен отдавать экземпляр нужной ВМ, когда я делаю на него  `Binding` на `Xaml`.

UPD

`Locator`

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private BaseViewModel baseVm;
    public BaseViewModel BaseVm
    {
        get { return new BaseViewModel(); }
    }
}
```

`App.xaml`

```
<viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
```

`MainPage.xaml` элементы которые забиндены на нужные мне св-ва из `BaseViewModel`

```
<Image Visibility="{Binding IsFilterImgVisible, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator} ,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>


<controls:ImageManipulatorControl 
      Visibility="{Binding IsUserControlVisibile, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
</controls:ImageManipulatorControl>
```

C контролом вообще отдельная беда, при такой записи, что-то прозрачное накладывается на часть экрана(подозреваю что это контрол, хотя `bool` изначально стоит `false`)

В базовой VM лежат `bool` свойства, которые меняются из дочерних VM применяя слово `this.`, но результата никакого

Comment: Если дочерние VM хотят работать с базовой, почему бы просто не передать ссылку на базовую в конструкторе? Locator нужен скорее для каких-то более продвинутых и сложных сценариев.

Comment: Конструктор дочерней VM должен получить ссылку на базовую? Или обе должны получать ссылки?

Comment: Ну, я бы делал так, да. Раздал бы в конструкторе дочерних VM им ссылку на базовую VM.

Comment: А если у меня уже есть экземпляры этих VM в `App.xaml`, я могу сразу на них сослаться или нужно писать  `BaseViewModel = new BaseViewModel()`

Comment: @VladD Xaml ругается что не может использовать конструкторы, потому что я там указал `BaseViewModel`

Comment: Я бы не создавал VM-ки в App.xaml, ведь при этом вы не сможете их связать. Лучше делать это в App.xaml.cs. Например, как [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520252/10105).

Comment: В `App.xaml.cs` не могу прописать `Datacontext` он не хочет использовать это пронстранство имен. Писал даже полностью

Comment: Странно, должно работать. Покажите ваш код и сообщение об ошибке, разберёмся.

Comment: @VladD Вот   http://joxi.ru/8Anz9kDiGBQoAO    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FrameworkElement.DataContext'

Comment: Не, вы что-то не совсем то делаете. Посмотрите, как сделано в [примере](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520252/10105). Вам нужно установить не DataContext объекта App, а главного окна. Которое нужно создать здесь, а не неявно через OnStartup.

Comment: @VladD Сделал по аналогии, но приложение постоянно крашится потому что не может найти ресурсы из `Xaml` сначала на VM ругался, я удалил, теперь на конверторы, а они то тут вообще ни при чем  Это в конструкторе `App`    `MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
            new MainPage()
            {
                DataContext = vm
            
            };`

Comment: А какие ресурсы? Я ж не могу угадать. Покажите код и сообщение об ошибке. Ну и просто `new MainPage()` судя по всему неправильно, вы ж должны страницу не только создать, но и показать?

Comment: @VladD обновил вопрос. Вроде как я понял App.xaml теперь не работвет

Comment: Смотрите, DataContext вам не надо устанавливать в XAML, вы его устанавливаете в коде. Но ещё раз, вы *не показываете созданную страницу**! Это не должно быть правильно. Ну а насчёт остальных ошибок, давайте код.

Comment: @VladD пока не нашел как ее показать, а вот по поводу ошибок,то ругается на все эти ресурсы  (`app.xaml`) http://joxi.ru/J2b4aWEHWxEnr6     Каждый раз как они встречаются в коде в `MainPage.xaml` в качестве `StaticResource` Все эти ресурсы нужно перенести в `App.cs`?

Comment: Нет, с ресурсами всё в порядке, ошибка в другом месте. А вы исправили проблему с тем, что вы не показываете страницу? Думаю, это поправит и другие проблемы.

Comment: @VladD Вроде показываю страницу. `mainPage.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));` mainPage переменная типа `MainPage`. Но все равн та же ошибка

Comment: Окей, я даже вроде набросал код, у меня работает. Посмотрите в ответ, и если останутся ошибки, пишите их, разберёмся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы создал `Singleton` класс в котором разместил все нужные свойства. Для обращения к ним использовал

```
MySingletonClass.InstanceProperty.PropertyToChange=/*value*/
```

при `Binding` необходимо тоже добавлять `Instance`, для того чтобы ссылаться на существующий экземпляр класса и соответсвенно свойства

```
"{Binding Instance.IsFilterImgVisible , Source={StaticResource EditModeSwitcher}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ох, это же UWP, там всё странно.

Я не нашёл метод «из коробки», как сделать так, чтобы View не знало о VM. Но это можно симулировать. Не знаю, насколько мой метод хорош, у меня мало опыта с UWP.

Итак, что мы делаем.

Для начала, главную VM и подчинённые VM создаём в классе `App`:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    MainVM mainVM;

    public App()
    {
        SetupVM();

        // стандартный код, сгенерированный шаблоном:
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    void SetupVM()
    {
        mainVM = new MainVM();
        var partVM = new PartVM(mainVM);
        var anotherPartVM = new AnotherPartVM(mainVM);
        mainVM.Part = partVM;          
        mainVM.AnotherPart = anotherPartVM;  
    }
```

Далее, поскольку навигация идёт лишь через `Frame.Navigate`, в котором невозможно указать экземпляр, а только тип (почему??), я передаю VM как параметр, чтобы окно само себе установило его в качестве VM:

```
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // тут много сгенерированного кода

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // здесь добавил mainVM вместо параметра
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), mainVM);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

Теперь в коде страницы:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        // вытаскиваем DataContext из параметров навигации
        DataContext = e.Parameter;
    }

    void OnNextClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // при навигации в другое окно передаём ему DataContext
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(NextPage), DataContext);
        // это новое окно тоже должно будет вытащить его из параметра, как и это
    }
}
```

Теперь, вложенный `UserControl`. Ему нужно передать правильный `DataContext`:

```
<local:InnerControl DataContext="{Binding Part}"/>
```

Наконец, при каком-нибудь действии внутри UserControl'а получает управление его VM, которая имеет у себя ссылку на `MainVM`.

Всё!

Comment: В параметрах навигации рекомендуется передавать примитивные типы ("рекомендуется" в данном случае означает, что только их следует передавать), потому что при засыпании приложения оно будет падать, т.к. не сможет сериализовать что-то сложное. Если надо передать объект, то следует его сериализовать и передать как строку.

Comment: @VladD  var partVM = new PartVM(mainVM);  Конструктор `PartVM` не имеет параметров, но принимает 1 аргумент, тоже самое на следующей строке. Если добавить в конструктор `PartVM` базовую VM тогда говорит, что базовая вью модель это тип, недействителен в текущем датаконтексте http://joxi.ru/RmzYVGOiKWZVrO

Comment: @MakeMakeluv: О господи! А как же тогда передать VM для View снаружи?

Comment: @SmiLe: Эээ... Ну блин, вы бы учебник почитали для начала. `BaseViewModel` у вас — это тип, а не переменная. Сформулируйте словами, где у вас главная VM, а где её вложенные, и какие у них типы. В соответствии с этим будет понятно, что делать.

Comment: @VladD А зачем ее передавать?
По теме вопроса - почему надо хранить это свойство именно в ВМ? Можно вынести его как статичное свойство во внешний статичный класс. А еще можно использовать `EventAggregator`, если опять же юзать `Prism`.

Comment: @MakeMakeluv: Потому что не дело View устанавливать себе VM. View не имеет права управлять VM (по крайней мере, в MVVM). И ещё проблема в том, что если даже согласиться на то, что View устанавливает себе VM, то тогда View должно и создать и связать все нужные VM, а это уж совсем за рамками его компетенции.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем делать свой велосипед, если можно воспользоваться готовым? [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/)