# Масштабирование интерфейса WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

Было разработано приложение с использованием WPF.

Заказчик использует приложение на планшете и интерфейс мелковат для быстрой работы, требуется увеличить все элементы, ну скажем, на 50%.

Как сделать это быстро и с меньшими затратами? В каждом `Window` применить к контейнеру компоновки трансформацию `Scale` в `RenderTransform`? Попробовал сделать это на примере одного из `Window` - окно и не знает, что содержимое увеличилось и оно в окно не влезает...

Как всё-таки правильно это сделать? На что при этом обратить внимание? А, может быть, есть способ сделать масштабирование динамическим с возможностью смены коэффициента во время работы (при работе с мышью ведь увеличение и не требуется)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если решать проблему так, как вы хотите (масштабированием интерфейса), то подойдёт следующая идея. Пусть вы увеличиваете всё в `k` раз (у вас `k = 1.5`). Пишем так:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid> <!-- внешний контейнер -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/> <!-- 0.5 = k - 1 -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/> <!-- 0.5 = k - 1 -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <!-- ScaleX/Y = k -->
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>

            <!-- ну и тут ваш контент -->
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnClick">
                GO
            </Button>
            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

(С удивлением обнаружил, что `RenderTransform` перемещает область hit test.)

---

Однако мне кажется, что это не идеальное решение. Дело в том, что простое скалирование интерфейса не поможет. Майкрософт пробовала в ранних версиях Windows Phone скалирование десктопных интерфейсов, и отказалась от этого: при таком подходе страдает usability.

Когда у вас мало места на экране, вы захотите не скалировать всё, а расположить элементы по-другому. Поэтому лучше следовать опыту Microsoft, и сделать для планшетов отдельный интерфейс, похожий на основной, но «заточенный» под меньший размер экрана и тач-управление. Будет выглядеть намного профессиональнее.

---

Дополнение: Если вам нужно менять размер в зависимости от разных обстоятельств, проще всего сделать его параметром. Это делается так:

1. В `MainWindow` кладём `DependencyProperty` типа `double`, назовём его `ScaleFactor`. Значение по умолчанию — `1.0`.

   ```
    public double ScaleFactor
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleFactorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScaleFactorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleFactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScaleFactor", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));
   ```
2. Вместо константы `1.5` в `ScaleY` прописываем привязку:

   ```
    {Binding ScaleFactor, ElementName=Main}
   ```

   (даём окну имя `Main`, чтобы было проще привязывать).
3. Для привязки `ColumnDefinition` нам нужно вычесть единицу и перейти от `double` к типу `GridLength`, поэтому используем конвертер. Для начала определим его:

   ```
    class RestGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type tt, object parameter, CultureInfo ci)
        {
            return new GridLength((double)value - 1, GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type tt, object parameter, CultureInfo ci)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
   ```

   Кладём в ресурсы и привязываем:

   ```
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ScaleFactor, ElementName=Main,
            Converter={StaticResource RestGridLengthConverter}}"/>
   ```
4. Всё, теперь у нас можно настраивать увеличение при старте программы (или вообще когда угодно), используя `ScaleFactor`.

Например, можно прикрутить к нему слайдер. Вот полный пример:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
        Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="Main">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:RestGridLengthConverter x:Key="RestGridLengthConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ScaleFactor, ElementName=Main,
                Converter={StaticResource RestGridLengthConverter}}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ScaleFactor, ElementName=Main,
                Converter={StaticResource RestGridLengthConverter}}"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0"
                                ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor, ElementName=Main}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor, ElementName=Main}"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="75">
                GO
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Slider Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Minimum="1" Maximum="5"
                Value="{Binding ScaleFactor, ElementName=Main}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
namespace Example
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double ScaleFactor
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleFactorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScaleFactorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleFactorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
               "ScaleFactor", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));
    }
}
```

```
namespace Example
{
    class RestGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type tt, object parameter, CultureInfo ci)
        {
            return new GridLength((double)value - 1, GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type tt, object parameter, CultureInfo ci)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Собственно, пока как временное решение поизменял в xaml-разметке margin/padding/fontsize у элементов, но на ПК выглядит мерзковато. Как тогда сделать 2 независимых разметки с возможностью их смены во время работы?

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, создайте два класса `MainWindowDesktop` и `MainWindowTablet`, и инстанциируйте нужный. Для этого вам понадобится создавать главное окно не неявно через `StartupUri`, а явно, как [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520252/10105).

Comment: Продолжаю изучение WPF, добрался до изучения стилей :). Может быть есть какое-то решение с использованием их? Сделать 2 набора стилей для элементов, при запуске приложения выбирать нужный...

Comment: @Андрей: Лучше не через стиль, а просто параметризировать через свойство. Смотрите обновление ответа.