# Отображение уникальных свойств различных объектов

Tags: wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте!

Нужно реализовать в программе вещь, похожую на панель инструментов Visual Studio.
То есть, к примеру, когда я выбираю в дереве объектов Button, то на панели свойств отображаются одни параметры, если же выбираю ListBox, то совсем другие. И таких объектов с уникальными параметрами достаточно много.

То есть мне нужно, чтобы когда выбран один объект, на этой "панели со свойствами" было 3 кнопки, 2 текстблока, а в другом случае иное количество этих элементов.

Как такое реализуется?
Создавать для каждого объекта из дерева UserControl в котором будет та самая панель со свойствами?

Comment: Может лучше начать с готового. Вот например https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home (и такого много). В общем гуглите "WPF Property Grid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выделить абстракцию из ваших объектов. Создать коллекцию типа абстрактного класса. Засунуть коллекцию например в `ListBox`, привязаться к `SelectedItem`, а в `ContentControl` уже отображать выбранный элемент, заранее определив для каждого объекта свой `DataTemplate`.

Пример:

```
public abstract class AbstractCustomObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

VM:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<AbstractCustomObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    private AbstractCustomObject _selectedObject;
    public AbstractCustomObject SelectedObject
    {
         get { return _selectedObject; }
         set { _selectedObject = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedObject"); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyObjects = new ObservableCollection<AbstractCustomObject>()
        {
            new Object1(){Name ="Объект 1"}, 
            new Object2(){Name ="Объект 2"}
        };      
    }
    // реализация INotifyPropertyChanged 
    // INotifyPropertyChanged - используется для уведомления представления об изменениях свойств объекта
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

теперь надо задать `DataContext` для нашего окна: посмотреть как это сделать можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520252/204383).

xaml-разметка:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Object1}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Button Content="button1"/>
                <Button Content="button2"/>
                <Button Content="button2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Object2}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                <Button Content="button2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedObject}"/>
```

Comment: Почему-то возникают ошибки в XAML разметке: говорит, что не видит Object1 и Object2. Можете скинуть готовый проект с применением данного кода?

Comment: @maxwell, на данный момент не имею возможности скинуть. По поводу ошибок, вы добавили пространство имен `local` где лежат классы `Object1` `Object2`?

Comment: Да, добавил. Если не затруднит посмотрите мой код в стартовом посте.

Comment: @maxwell, обновил ответ

Comment: Так все работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @maxwell, пожалуйста!