# Простенький Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать простенький биндинг, не могу разобраться.

Есть класс:

```
class Groups
{
    private string Name { get; set; }
```

Есть Xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="groupName" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Как из кодбихайнда привязать к (private string Name) какую-либо строку и вывести ее в тот самый биндинг?

Comment: Сейчас дежурный по сайту @VladD вам ответит =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны сделать несколько вещей.

Во-первых, ваше свойство должно быть публичным:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Затем, вы должны установить объект, содержащий это свойство, в качестве `DataContext`'а. `Binding` обычно производится к `DataContext`'у.

Ну и наконец, чтобы UI могло подхватывать ваши изменения, класс `Groups` должен как-то о них сообщать. Например, реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class Groups : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { if (name != value) { name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }}
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Всё!

Comment: Немного непонятно с DataContext, Создаю экземпляр класса Groups g = new Groups(), потом присваиваю g.Name какую-то строку, потом groupName.DataContext = g.Name. В xaml изменил DataContext="{Binding Name}". Не выводит :( Где опять накосячил?

Comment: Все кроме класса Groups находится в конструкторе, в классе Groups реализовал интерфейс так же как вы написали.

Comment: @Дмитрий: А что такое GroupName? Должно быть по идее `window.DataContext = g;` (не `g.Name`).

Comment: groupName это x:Name текстблока, я не могу понять как в свойство Name правильно передать строку. Можете привести пример как правильно задать в Name строку и привязать ее к биндингу, не могу понять логику Биндингов

Comment: @Дмитрий: Не-не, `DataContext` нужно устанавливать по идее у всего окна. Ну остальное же всё правильно. А о каком именно свойстве `Name` вы говорите в последнем комментарии? Если это `g.Name`, то просто `g.Name = "значение"`.

Comment: Вывел, но мне кажется можно все это дело упростить, пришлось создавать метод Page_Loaded, в нем создавать эксземпляр класса Groups, делать this.DataContext = g; Потом в конструкторе опять же создавать экземпляр класса Groups и уже потом только присваиваю g.Name какую-то строку, потом groupName.Text = g.Name

Comment: @Дмитрий: Обычно делается как-то так: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520252/10105 (смотрите последнюю часть, начиная от «Кстати, и главное окно...»).