# Не могу разобраться ObservableCollection с ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Проблема скорее всего в привязке. В ListBox не прибавляются элементы.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyList x:Key="MyData"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="temp">
        <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" CornerRadius="4" Width="370">
            <Grid Margin="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="100" Height="75" Margin="6"
                       Source="{Binding Path=Img}"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,6">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Surname}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= Country}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource temp}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyData}}" x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="258" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="358"/>
    <Button x:Name="Add" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="388,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Add_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="Edit" Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="388,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Edit_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="Remove" Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="387,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Remove_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Вот сам клас:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Window1 wd;
    private MyList MyData;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyData = new MyList();
        MyData.Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));
        MyData.Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));

    }


}
class MyList : ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> MyData;
    public MyList() : base()
    {
        MyData = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        MyData.Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));
        MyData.Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));
    }
}
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public Image Img { get; set; }
    public Person(string name, string surname, string country, Image img)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Country = country;
        Img = img;
    }
    public Person() { }

}
```

Comment: а что вы хотите получить? То что вы можете увидеть, это два элемента Person в листе MyData. Вообще присутствует некоторая путаница. Сначала снаружи вы объявляете переменную MyData типа MyList, затем объявляете переменную MyData типа ObservableCollection<Person>. Тут абсолютно запутана логика

Comment: а `DataContext` вы где задаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Где вы находите такие способы создания коллекций?)

Ну, исправим то что есть:

```
<local:MyList x:Key="MyData"/>
```

Объект создается в ресурсе окна, соответственно добавление элементов в коллекцию должно происходить в конструкторе этого объекта. То что вы добавляете элементы в *.cs файле, это не совсем то, так как это не тот объект к которому вы привязываетесь.(привязка идет к объекту созданному в ресурсе).

Идем дальше. Раз уж вы решили создать коллекцию унаследовавшись от нее самой, то добавляйте элементы унаследованным методом:

```
public class MyList : ObservableCollection<Person>
{        
    public MyList() : base()
    {
        Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));
        Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));
    }
}
```

В принципе все, должно работать.

---

Пару замечаний по вашему коду:

> ```
> public ObservableCollection<Person> MyData;
> ```

Если вы будете привязываться к MyData то привязка не пройдет. Привязка работает только со свойствами, т.е. должно выглядеть так:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> MyData { get; set; }
```

---

**Как это делается обычно**:

В проекте должен быть класс VM, реализующий интерфейс [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Этот класс будет являться DataContext-oм для вашего окна([как задать DataContext](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520252/204383)). В этом классе и объявить список:

```
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public ObservableCollection<Person> MyList { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        MyList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        MyList.Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));
        MyList.Add(new Person("1", "2", "3", null));
    }  

    //---------------------
    //реализация интерфейса
}   //---------------------
```

После таких манипуляций, использовать привязку одно удовольствие:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, но как в этом случае добавлять или редактировать элементы?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Я дополнил ответ, посмотрите.