# DataContext и ViewModel (Entity Framework)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, дорогие знатоки. Разрабатываю WPF app (EntityFramework, Sqlite, MMVM). Такой вопрос возник у меня:

Есть обычная **ViewModel**:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext(); //контекст
    public ObservableCollection<Record> Records { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {     
        Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(context.Records.ToList());
    }
}
```

В **MainWindow.xaml** добавляю так:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

...иии после волшебных манипуляций XAMLдизайнера, я получаю:

[image: Ошибка]

а также: зависший секунд на 10 Visual Studio, предупреждение о том, что сведения о задержке отправлены в Майкрософт и т.д. И так каждый раз когда я переключаюсь с кода в XAML редактор.

Хотя после запуска приложения все отлично с binding's, все отлично работает. Есть вариант перенести все в code-behind и делать: *DataContext = new ViewModel()*, но данный способ не подходит с религиозных причин.
Спасибо за внимание.

**UPDATE:**
Дизайнер ругается на эту строчку: `Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(context.Records.ToList());`
Он почему-то не может получить доступ к данным контекста. Как его перехитрить?

Comment: с connectionString все отлично.

Comment: Советую задавать `DataContext` на code-behind. А еще лучше - используйте Dependency Injection.

Comment: @AGS17 не лучшая идея задавать `DataContext` в `code-behind`.

Comment: @sp7 вообще плохая идея это делать собственноручно. Но если выбирать между заданием на вьюхе и заданием на code-behind - второй вариант выглядит куда логичней.

Comment: Вы делаете неправильно. EF-entity — это модель, а не VM. И работать с ними в UI-потоке категорически воспрещено, если вы, конечно, не хотите, чтобы ваше приложение висло время ото времени.

Comment: @AresGod, а вам очень сильно нужны данные из БД во время разработки? Если нет, посмотрите этот топик: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678612/intellisense-для-viewmodel-в-редакторе-xaml-visual-studio а `DataContext` устанавливайте в другом месте

Comment: @Андрей, спасибо, полезно. Но хотелось все-таки решить свою проблему с IsDesignTimeCreatable, которое не работает.

Comment: @VladD, т.е. нужно грузить данные асинхронно от UI? Во ViewModel await-ить? Все CRUD действия делать используя асинхронные команды?

Comment: @AresGod: Ну, это было бы вообще идеальным решением, да.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, это уже реализовал. Только не понял как мне асинхронно присвоить свойству obserable collection.
Пока что сделал так:
        `private async Task LoadData(object param)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Records.Clear();
                foreach(var item in Context.Records)
                {
                    Records.Add(item);
                }
            }
}`

Хотелось бы что-то на подобии: `await Task.Run(()=>Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(context.Records); }`

Comment: @AresGod: Вам нужно асинхронно получить модельные данные (то есть, сделать запрос к базе), и затем в UI-потоке создать на них VM-обёртки (не к модельным же данным биндиться?) Если данных реально много (по идее, это уже не очень, т. к. юзер вряд ли сможет прочитать и понять миллион строк), то лучше сделать либо объекты иммутабельными, либо грузить лениво, по частям и только по запросу.

Comment: @VladD, у меня не большой проект. Записей порядка несколько десятков тысяч. Лениво и так грузиться все. Мне главное сделать все операции без фриза UI, с остальным проблем не будет) А так, спасибо за информацию

Comment: @AresGod: Кстати, по поводу установки DataContext в XAML'е: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520245/10105 (хотя вопрос, конечно, религиозный).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**РЕШЕНИЕ**: Сделал временно все в `Code-behind`, а для включения подсказок в IntelliSence использую: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}"` *Подробнее*: [IntelliSense для ViewModel в редакторе XAML Visual Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678612/intellisense-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-viewmodel-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-xaml-visual-studio)