# IntelliSense для ViewModel в редакторе XAML Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, intellisense

При разработке `WPF` `MVVM` приложения у нас в разметке `XAML` повсеместно используется `Binding`, как получить удобство разработки в виде подсказок `IntelliSense` при вводе названий свойств из `VM`? Ведь, если мы ошибемся хотя бы в одном символе, привязка работать не будет, поэтому приходится часто переключаться между файлами проекта и копировать имена (а если `VM` собрана в библиотеку и исходника вообще у нас нет?).

Причем если в разметке указать что-то типа:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

(и собрать проект) то `IntelliSense` начинает помогать.
Но я ведь хочу быть хорошим разработчиком и, по рекомендациям, такую зависимость делать не хочу (и мне это в общем-то понятно).

Какие вы знаете и/или используете способы для включения подсказок в такой ситуации (есть ли они вообще)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Решение удалось найти самостоятельно. Подсмотрел здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394295/intellisense-for-data-binding-not-working

Выглядит оно так:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainVM}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" ...
```

т.е. в `XAML` должно быть подключено пространство имен `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"` (оно подключено по умолчанию при создании нового окна) и тогда можно воспользоваться фичей: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainVM}"`, при этом если указать параметр `IsDesignTimeCreatable=True`, то студия будет пытаться создать экземпляр указанной `VM` прямо во время работы в дизайнере и наполнять форму реальными данными (что иногда может замедлить работу дизайнера или даже повалить его)

Comment: Ещё по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/569964/10105