# Оригинальный размер изображения

Tags: c#, wpf

Программно добавляю картинку, но как устанавливать ей оригинальный размер как у источника, а не `auto` или от себя ?

Таким образом она расширяется на всю возможную площадь

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Вы хотите чтобы Image принял размеры помещенного в него изображения?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, вы правильно меня поняли

Comment: За "обрезание" изображения отвечает такой параметр, как `Stretch`. Пробуйте установить в `None`

Comment: Поместите Image в контейнер, который даёт дочернему элемента столько места, сколько он просит. Это может быть даже обычный Grid, например, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863379/218063

Comment: Полный код размещения Image покажите, в какой контейнер кладете?