# Передача разных типо данных в аргумент функции c#

Tags: c#, функции

В коде у 4-ех свойств повторяются сеттеры (ActivityStatus, TimeSpan(2), DataTime). Требуется убрать повторения путем написание функции. Но как передавать аргумент в функцию.
object - придется приводить тип данных (много кода увеличится)
шаблоны - аналогично первому 
перегрузка функция - еще больше повторений будет

```
 public DateTime/ActivityStatus/TimeSpan NameOfProperty
        {
            private set
            {
                if (_privateFields != value)
                {
                    _privateFields = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NameOfProperty));
                }
            }
            get => _privateFields;
        }
```

Comment: Покажите код, дженерики не подойдут?

Comment: @АндрейNOP прикрепил

Comment: Возьмите базовый Vm-класс отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863379/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP  взял SetProperty у Prism и все, но спасибо за ваш ответ