# Сохранение картинки из image в папку с экзешником

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

[image: Ошибка]

Есть `image` в который ранее была загружена картинка, надо по нажатию на кнопку скопировать это изображение в папку `images`, которая лежит в папке с экзешником (без открытия диалогового окна).
Уже много вариантов попробовал,не могу добиться результата...

Если знаете вариант лучше, можете его написать.

- `FirstImage` мой image
- `nametext` поле в которое вводится название

Нужен хотя бы пример копирования ранее загруженной картинки.

**Загрузка картинки:**

```
private void Donwnlimg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.FileName = ""; // Default file name
    // dlg.DefaultExt = ".png"; // Default file extension
    dlg.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                 "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                 "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";   // Filter files by extension
    // Show open file dialog box
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    // Process open file dialog box results
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document
        Firstimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName));
    }
}
```

**Мои попытки:**

```
private void vnecti(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("images//" + nametext.Text + ".jpg", FileMode.CreateNew);
    string stroka = fs.Name;
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(nametext.Text);
    f.CopyTo(stroka);
}
```

Comment: Пользователь в диалоговом окне выбирает картинку

Comment: В это и проблема,ни как не получается.В примере кода выше я пытался так сделать,но изображение не копируется,создается просто файл jpg,пустой

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863379/218063

Comment: А при чем тут это изображение с ошибкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)Firstimage.Source));
        using (var stream = File.Create(@"images//"+nametext.Text+".png"))
            encoder.Save(stream);
```

- Изображения сохраняются в папку images(там лежит мой экзешник)
- nametext.Text текст введенный туда будет именем моего файла
- Входные файлы конвертируются в png