# WPF - удалить часть фона. Crop rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity, crop

Я пишу приложение, которое по функционалу похоже на стандартное виндосовское приложение "Ножницы".
Открывается приложение во весь экран, сам экран затемняется путем наложения грида черного с опасити 50%.
далее мне надо мышкой нарисовать прямоугольник, типа выделяя зону вырезания. Так вот заливка этого прямоугольника должна игнорировать черный грид и показывать область под программой без изменения цвета. Есть у кого нибудь идея как сделать такой прямоугольник?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude"`, пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863379/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо огромное, вы прям помогли мне напасть на верный след!