# Как разделить картинку (WPF C#)&

Tags: c#, wpf, background-image

Подскажите как разделить картинку(программно) на прямоугольники как показано на картинке.(Рамки это border'ы). Часть фоновой картинки должна быть привязана к бордеру который находится над этой областью и при удалении/перемещении элемента картинка также удалялась/перемещалась. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863379/218063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам вовсе не нужно делить картинку. Вы просто кладёте ваш рисунок в фон, а перемещающиеся части реализуете при помощи `UserControl`-ов.

Давайте реализуем эту идею.

У меня получилась вот такая разметка:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Title="Test" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Canvas Height="384" Width="512">
        <Image Height="384" Width="512" Source="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10"  Canvas.Top="10"  Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="10"  Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="10"  Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10"  Canvas.Top="140" Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="140" Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="140" Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10"  Canvas.Top="270" Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="270" Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="270" Height="100" Width="150" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="20"  Canvas.Top="20"  Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-10"  OffsetY="-10"  Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="10"  Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-180" OffsetY="-10"  Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="10"  Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-350" OffsetY="-10"  Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="10"  Canvas.Top="140" Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-10"  OffsetY="-140" Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="140" Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-180" OffsetY="-140" Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="140" Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-350" OffsetY="-140" Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="10"  Canvas.Top="270" Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-10"  OffsetY="-270" Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="270" Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-180" OffsetY="-270" Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
        <local:ImagePart Canvas.Left="350" Canvas.Top="270" Height="100" Width="150"
                         OffsetX="-350" OffsetY="-270" Image="Resources/img.jpg"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

и такое определение `ImagePart`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.ImagePart"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Border Margin="-1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Canvas
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                  AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            ClipToBounds="True">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding OffsetX}" Canvas.Top="{Binding OffsetY}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
    <UserControl.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="DarkGray"/>
    </UserControl.Effect>
</UserControl>
```

и code-behind

```
public partial class ImagePart : UserControl
{
    public ImagePart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Image), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImagePart));

    public int OffsetX
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(OffsetXProperty);
        set => SetValue(OffsetXProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetXProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(OffsetX), typeof(int), typeof(ImagePart));

    public int OffsetY
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(OffsetYProperty);
        set => SetValue(OffsetYProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetYProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(OffsetY), typeof(int), typeof(ImagePart));
}
```

В главном окне на Canvas'е лежат: фоновая картинка, 9 серых прямоугольников, которые «вырезают» на ней кусочки, и 9 UserControl'ов, представляющих собой движущиеся части картинки.

У `ImagePart` я добавил три dependency property: картинка, и смещение картинки в UserControl'е по X и по Y.

В каталог Resources я положил картинку [img.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9yZb.jpg). Размер картинки 512 × 384, и все константы в коде подогнаны под этот размер. Если в вашем коде размер картинки не фиксирован, вам прижётся перевычислять размеры (либо в code-behind, либо при помощи layout manager'а).

Вот что получилось:

[image: скриншот]

Левый верхний кусочек я специально поместил немного в стороне, чтобы было видно, что он отдельно.

Как обеспечить перемещение кусочков, можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/10105).